# why is .First necessary in this Linq-To-Xml query?

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

this is my xml file:

```
<Corsi>
  <corso ID="0" nome="Corso 1" quota="100" dataCorso="24/08/2012"></corso>
  <corso ID="1" nome="Corso 2" quota="100" dataCorso="04/09/2012"></corso>
  <corso ID="2" nome="Corso 3" quota="100" dataCorso="14/09/2012"></corso>
  <corso ID="3" nome="Corso 4" quota="100" dataCorso="20/08/2012"></corso>
  <corso ID="4" nome="Corso 5" quota="100" dataCorso="30/09/2012"></corso>
</Corsi>
```

query 1: works

```
var QUERY = docCorsi.Descendants("corso")
            .Where(a => (int)a.Attribute("ID") == Convert.ToInt16(txtNomeAgenzia.Text))
            .Select(a =>a.Attribute("dataCorso").Value)
            .First();
```

query 2: doesn't work

```
var QUERY = docCorsi.Descendants("corso")
            .Where(a => (int)a.Attribute("ID") == Convert.ToInt16(txtNomeAgenzia.Text))
            .Select(a =>a.Attribute("dataCorso").Value);
```

Can anyone explain why is .First necessary even if I'm sure that query returns only one result?

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't an adequate error description. Are you getting a compiler error? An exception?

Comment: after querying I use  DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(QUERY);                                           and the exception is: System.InvalidCastException: Impossibile eseguire il cast di oggetti di tipo 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,System.String]' sul tipo 'System.IConvertible'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that a normal LINQ query always returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, even when there is only one result. Appending `First` returns the first element that is returned by the query. If you are sure that there can be only one, you could also use `Single`.

Comment: "query always returns an IEnumerable<T>" Perfect! Exactly what I want to be sure of. Thanks Daniel!